# Multi criterion search in Excel data base returning multiple results

Tags: excel, vba

Assume the follwing data base structure:

```
GId  IId  CId  EId
==================
  1    1    1    1
  1    2    1    1
  1    3    1    1
  2    2    2    2
  3    1    1    1
  3    2    1    1
  3    4    1    1
  4    1    3    2
```

Now I want to use (if possible) worksheet functions to realizes a query to the data base which does the following:

```
**Search Criteria**
IIds: 1, 2, 4
CId:  1, 3
```

Now I would like to check the table to see whether there is a `GId` which matches this criterion. *Matches* in this sense means that there is a `GId` where all `IIds/CIds` occur in the search string. In this example this is the case for `GId = 3, 4`:

- for `GId = 1` the `IId = 3` is *not* part of the search string
- for `GId = 2` the `CId = 2` is *not* part of the search string
- for `GId = 3` all `IId = (1, 2, 4)` are part of the search string as well as `CId = 1`
- for `GId = 4` `IId = 1` and `CId = 3` are part of the search string.

For what it matters: the `GId` is a grouping ID. For each group I can have several Ingredient IDs (`IId`) and *one* Condition ID (`CId`) and *one* Effect ID (`EId`). If it helps I could also think of splitting the table into two tables:

```
GId   IId   |  GId   CId   EId
============+=================
  1     1   |    1     1     1
  1     2   |    2     2     2
  1     3   |    3     1     1
  2     2   |    4     3     2
  3     1   |
  3     2   |
  3     4   |
  4     1   |
```

So no my question: how shoudl I approach this query? SHould I write an VBA function which loops through all `GIds` and check whether all the related `IIds` are part of this `GId` or is there a solution working with area formulas?

Comment: Seems to me that sql queries in access would be better for this than Excel.  In excel you will probably have better luck with vba.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something in the line of SQL. However, Access is not an option becasue it has to be used by Excel users and we cannot rely on an Access backend. Anyway how I could use SQL in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses `AutoFilter` to select the resulting range. It could highlight in place the resulting range or extract it to another range.

```
Sub Data_Extract_1()
Dim aFieldCriteria As Variant
aFieldCriteria = Array("IId\1,2,4", "CId\1,3")      'change as required
Dim rDta As Range, rOutput As Range
Dim rArea As Range, rCll As Range, vItm As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA.2")              'change as required
        If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .Cells(1).AutoFilter
        Set rDta = .Range("B6").CurrentRegion       'change as required
    End With

    With rDta

        For Each vItm In aFieldCriteria
            vItm = Split(vItm, "\")
            vItm(0) = WorksheetFunction.Match(vItm(0), .Rows(1), 0)
            .AutoFilter Field:=vItm(0), Criteria1:=Split(vItm(1), ","), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Next

        Rem Higlights Results
        .Offset(1).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = RGB(224, 232, 248)

        Rem Extracts Results
        Set rOutput = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Set rCll = .Offset(0, 3 + .Columns.Count)   'change as required
        .AutoFilter

    End With

    For Each rArea In rOutput.Areas
        With rArea
            rCll.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = rArea.Value2
            Set rCll = rCll.Offset(.Rows.Count).Resize(1, 1)
    End With: Next

End Sub
```